# Separate html and js for a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am trying to insert a list of JS objects (with multiple attributes) into a html list. In my html I have a simple list markup

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class='list-item'>
        <span class='date'></span>
        <span class='lan'></span>
        <span class='topic'></span>
        <span class='speaker'></span>
        <a class ='play' title='Listen' href=""><i class='fa fa-play-circle-o'></i></a>
        <a class ='download' title='Download' href=""><i class='fa fa-download'></i></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In the JS file, I have a variable named values contains those object with a piece of code

```
for (var i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    $(".date").append(values[i].date);
    $('.lan').append(values[i].lan);
    $('.topic').append(values[i].topic);
    $('.speaker').append(values[i].speaker);
    $('.play').attr('href', values[i].play);
    $('.download').attr('href', values[i].link);
};
```

The result is there is only one list-item and the values just keep concat. I think I should create multiple "list-item" but I gave a couple tries and haven't been succeed. Could anyone give me some hints or help. Thx.

Comment: You have to create another <li> tag

Comment: the thing you are tring to do is handled by frontend frameworks like AngularJS. If you really want to implement it, then you have to create `<li>` tags as Ludo said, and to add in the li all the span, a and the sub-elements needed.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to accomplish this is to use templates. You can use a template engine (moustache, etc.) or do it yourself :

```
<script type = "text/template" id="template">
  <li>
    <span class="a"></span>    
    <span class="b"></span>
  </li>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var values = [
      {a : 1, b : 2},
      {a : 2, b : 3}
    ]

    for (var i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      var value = values[i];
      var element = $($('#template').html());
      element.find('.a').html(value.a);
      element.find('.b').html(value.b);
      $('.list').append(element);
    };


</script>

<ul class="list">

</ul>
```

Comment: Like the template approach. I don't like to write the DOM inside JS. It make styling harder. Thx

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `li` tag, put your variables in there and then append the whole thing to your `.list`.

```
for (var i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var item = $("<li class='list-item'>\
        <span class='date'></span>\
        <span class='lan'></span>\
        <span class='topic'></span>\
        <span class='speaker'></span>\
        <a class ='play' title='Listen' href=''><i class='fa fa-play-circle-o'></i></a>\
        <a class ='download' title='Download' href=''><i class='fa fa-download'></i></a>\
        </li>");
    item.find(".date").append(values[i].date);
    item.find('.lan').append(values[i].lan);
    item.find('.topic').append(values[i].topic);
    item.find('.speaker').append(values[i].speaker);
    item.find('.play').attr('href', values[i].play);
    item.find('.download').attr('href', values[i].link);
    $(".list").append(item);
};
```

You also need to clean out your `ul` tag. It should contain nothing as the script will add the item's `li` tag itself.

You might also change the inner `.append`s to `.text` or `.html`, depending on your requirements.

See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ybmTErpcxLfIIqADRpmf?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

You are appending the values which is not what you want.

try to pass only the variable in the span:

```
$(".date").text(values[i].date);
```

This is the simple way according with your markup.

Alternatively you can use @Amir answer creating a complete new 'li' element and then append it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I do not suggest you to use the approach you have in the code. In your case I would have something like this (try it):

```
    var list = $('.list');
   list.empty();
 for (var i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

  var t = $('<li class="list-item" />');
  t.append('<span class="date">' + values[i].date + '</span>');
  t.append('<span class="lan">' + values[i].lan + '</span>');
  t.append('<span class="topic">' + values[i].topic + '</span>');
  list.append(t);

 }
});
```